# Accessing classes within a jar placed in a dependent plugin

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, rcp, eclipse-pde

I have the following usecase. I have added a jar file(generated out of maven) as an external jar in the bundle path of a plugin (say Plugin A).

I have exposed all the packages inside this jar in Plugin A.

Now Plugin A is added as a dependency to Plugin B.

But in Plugin B, I am not able to access the classes inside the jar file which is added as an external jar to Plugin A and whose packages are exposed

Is it advisable to the same jar in every plugin ? Please pour in your suggestions.

Comment: Show us the manifest.mf for plugin A.

Comment: When add plugin A as a dependendy to plugin B, What its the scope of this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue . In eclipse there is an option to generate a plugin from JAR file.So I have created a plugin from the jar file and added it as dependency to other plugin(after exposing the packages in the generated plugin).